# ReadableStream prefix of undefined

Tags: javascript, stream, blob, undefined

I'm trying to use the reader of a ReadableStream from a stream returned from a blob. Whenever I try to write the contents of the files it prefixes with undefined followed by the chars from the stream.

Example:
`\\undefinedContents from the files`. The undefined prefix is not part of the bytes returned from the stream. If I print them one by one I only see the expected content from the blob.

My code

```
function readStream(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    const stream = file.stream()
    const reader = stream.getReader()


    function readTheStream() {

        reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {

            if(done) {
                reader.cancel()
            }
            const ul = document.createElement('ul')
            let column;
            let tableRow = document.createElement('tr')
            for (let i = 0; i < value.buffer.byteLength; i++) {
                const char = String.fromCharCode(value[i])
                if(i < 10) console.log(char)


                if (char === " ") {
                    continue
                }

                if (char === "\n") {

                    ul.appendChild(tableRow)


                    column = ""
                    tableRow = document.createElement('tr')
                    continue
                }

                if (char === "\t") {
                    const td = document.createElement('td')
                    td.textContent = column
                    if (tableRow) {
                        tableRow.appendChild(td)

                    }
                    column = ""
                    continue

                }

                column += char

            }

            //Last row appended here cause no new line for creating it.
            ul.appendChild(tableRow)
            document.body.appendChild(ul)

        })
    }

    readTheStream()
```

The file is a normal textfile of 4 columns separated by tabs, and every column gets extracted and placed as expected with in my list, except for the first entry, which gets prefix with undefinedContents.

What could be causing this prefix?

You can see in this image how it displays:
[image: You can see in this image how it displays]

Answer (score 0):

Well this was a no brainer really. It has to do with me trying to append to an uninitialized string. The column var was simply declared. When I initialized it as an empty string, undefined disappeared.